# Vue.js - Duplicate keys using v-for in AccordionTab (Primevue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, primevue

I'm trying to generate an AccordionTab (component from Primevue) for each object of an array:

```
<Accordion>
  <AccordionTab v-for="curso in cursos.curso" :key="curso.descripcion" :header="curso.descripcion">
    {{ curso.descripcion }}
  </AccordionTab>
</Accordion>
```

It actually seems to work as intended, but the browser console shows a warning like this for each object in the array:

> [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'Primero'. This may cause an update error.

I've already checked and the array the `v-for` is iterating over and every object has a different value in the field specified as key, so why is it giving that warning?

**EDIT:**
Here's an screenshot of my Vue Devtools Console, showing the data I have in my component:

[image: data in the component]

And if I change the code to this, having the index as the key:

```
<Accordion :multiple="true">
  <AccordionTab v-for="(curso, index) in cursos.curso" :key="index" :header="curso.descripcion">
    {{ curso.descripcion }}
    {{ index }}
  </AccordionTab>
</Accordion>
```

The warning disappears, and the rendered component is this one:

[image: rendered]

It shows once again that the data is not actually duplicated, so I still don't know where the warning came from, maybe it could come from Primevue's component implementation.

Comment: We as humans sometimes make mistakes checking equality of values, computers usually don't. Have you looked for `Primero` in your `descripcion` values inside `cursos.curso`?

Comment: Yeah, I've edited the question to show it. Maybe I'm missing something, but there really seems that there is no duplicated data.

Answer (score 3):

Its seems that you have two or more `cursos` with the same `descripcion` which generates this issue, so try to use the `index` as a key like :

```
<AccordionTab v-for="(curso,index) in cursos.curso" :key="index" :header="curso.descripcion">
    {{ curso.descripcion }}
  </AccordionTab>
```

Comment: This makes the warning disappear, but the data is not duplicated (unless I'm missing something), I've edited to show it.

Comment: it's a weird behavior since the description is not duplicated